SORT to merge two files and append data without changing lrecl
I have two files with the same layout and LRECL
FIELD NAME          FIELD LENGTH
STORE-CUSTOM-ID     X(08)
STORE-GROUP         X(25)
STORE-LIST          9(04) OCCURS 500 TIMES

I want to Merge these two files based on STORE-CUSTOM-ID – first 8 bytes

If matched

Merged matched records into 1 record
Change store-group = ‘Merged Record’


If not matched

Write both records to output



Example:
Input
File1:
11223344File 1 Record            000900210022003400000000000000000000
File2:
11223344File 2 Record            100310121014000000000000000000000000
The key is the first 8 bytes. This records need to be merged.
Output:
11223344Merged Record            000900210022003410031012101400000000
Not necessarily there must be same number of STORE-LIST present in each record. For instance, in the above example, there are 4 store numbers in File1 and 3 store numbers in File2 for this key. There may be other records where there are 20 stores in File1 and 24 stores in File2. So, whenever there is a match, I need to Merge the records and when I encounter a ‘0000’ in the File1 then I need to start merging the store numbers from File2 from that position.
If we can achieve it thru SORT could you please help me with the SYSIN details?

I'd write a COBOL program to do the sort.  That way, you can print a summary page showing how many file 1 records, file 2 records, and combined records were passed along or created.

You can use DFSORT's Joinkeys feature to merge the records.  Here is a sample
//STEP0100 EXEC PGM=SORT   
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*     
//INA      DD DISP=SHR,DSN=your.input.FB.2033.byte.file1
//INB      DD DISP=SHR,DSN=your.input.FB.2033.byte.file2
//SORTOUT  DD DSN=Your.output.file,
//            DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),      
//            SPACE=(CYL,(X,Y),RLSE)
//SYSIN    DD *                                             
  OPTION COPY                                               
  JOINKEYS F1=INA,FIELDS=(1,8,A)                            
  JOINKEYS F2=INB,FIELDS=(1,8,A)                            
  JOIN UNPAIRED                                             
  REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,2033,                               
                   F2:1,2033,                               
                   ?)                                       
                                                            
  INREC IFOUTLEN=2033,                                      
          IFTHEN=(WHEN=(4067,1,CH,EQ,C'B'),                 
               OVERLAY=(0009:C'MERGED RECORD           ')), 
          IFTHEN=(WHEN=(4067,1,CH,EQ,C'2'),                 
                 BUILD=(2034,2033))                         
/*              


In this above SORT Card where do I append the file2 record into the position in file1 record where a 0000 begins?

Not sure what you meant by 0000 begins?  Do you mean in the array of STORE-LIST which occurs 500 times?
File-1- record : 1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 0000
File-2- record : 1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666 7777 8888 9999
Now you want to replace the output record store list as this?
Output record : 1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666 7777 8888 9999
if the store list is updated in File-2 record, why not simply update the Store-list from File-2 itself in the output record?

No, Its not the same store-list values in both the files. What you mentioned here is right- I want it that way but I cannot simply move file2 record to output:
Example,
File 1 :
11223344File1 Record             000100020003000400050000000000000000000000000000
File2:
11223344File2 Record             000600070008000900100000000000000000000000000000
Output should look like:
11223344Merged Record            000100020003000400050006000700080009001000000000
In each record out of the 2000 (4 occurs 500) there many be n number of store values which vary for each record.

you would  need about 500 IFTHEN statements and stackoverflow has a limit of 30,000 characters for answers. So I cannot add the control cards here.

I finished it using a cobol, thanks
